# cannot reach controller method in SpringBoot

Tags: java

I'm new to Spring Boot and I'm playing around with it trying to get a response from my backend.

The web server and application are running without errors but when I try to get "Hello World" by typing localhost:8080/api/hello I get a 404 not found.

This is the controller method

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class EmployeeController {


      @GetMapping("/hello")
      public String greeting() {
        return "Hello, World";
      }

   }
```

This is the response I get

[the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kjcm.png)

Comment: The address bar in your screenshot just shows "/hello" as path in the URL, not "/api/hello". How comes?

Comment: The URL in the browser seems to be localhost:8080/hello. Missed api?

Comment: I tried both with api and without api and the result is the same

Comment: What does your main class look like?

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo2Application {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);
 }

}`

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your api path as `api/hello`, but based on the screenshot of your request you are calling `/hello`.

Comment: I tried both with api and without api and the result is the same

Comment: I think your controllers are not scanned by the spring, try @ComponentScan(basePackages = "path.to.your.controller.package.*")

Comment: You have to add this in your main SpringApplication class.

Comment: The problem was indeed that my controller was not in the same package as main function

Comment: It's better to put your controllers in a separate package, then add a @ComponentScan to your main class to scan your controllers.

Comment: Doesn't the @SpringBootApplication annotation do the component scan ?

Answer (score 0):

use `localhost:8080/api/hello` ,
it will a solution for your problem